# Is there a way to list IAM roles in a different account through code?

Tags: java, python, amazon-web-services, sdk, amazon-iam

In Account A I have Role A. Role A has an attached policy allowing Role A to assume a set of roles in Account B. Role A can assume any roles matching the pattern 'arn:aws:iam::AccountB:role/roleB*'

While using the permissions of Role A, I'd like to list all of the roles in Account B that match the pattern defined in the attached policy. Using boto3, I tried to use the IAM client's list_roles method, but it only returns roles in Role A's account. The only work around I can think of is first assuming one of the roles in Account B, and then trying the list_roles method but it seems like an unnecessary step. Do I have a simpler option?

Comment: That is the only way to do it. You need to assume the role in the another account to list resources in that account.

Comment: Have you tried assuming a role with boto3? https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sts.html